# Access Here XYZ Studio Map GeoJSON via API?

Tags: here-api

I'm wondering if there's a way to build a map in Here XYZ Studio but then get said map's GeoJSON via one of the Here APIs.

Answer (score 0):

**HERE Maps API for Javascript** can render your XYZ Studio spaces directly:

```
// Assumption: the platform is instantiated
var service = platform.getXYZService({
      token: 'authentication_token_goes_here'
    }),
    provider = new H.service.xyz.Provider(service, 'space_id_goes_here');
map.addLayer(new H.map.layer.TileLayer(provider));
```

doc: https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.14.0/api_reference/H.service.xyz.Provider.html

---

It also can render geojson features:

```
var reader = new H.data.geojson.Reader('/path/to/geojson/file.json');
reader.parse();
// Assumption: map already exists
map.addLayer(reader.getLayer());
```

doc: https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.14.0/api_reference/H.data.geojson.Reader.html

---

Here is simple jsfiddle example of loading geojson features (country shapes):

https://jsfiddle.net/vhwfg8t4/